# Different threads access different memory locations concurrently

Tags: c++, memory

In C++14, there is a sentense like:

```
Different threads of execution are always allowed to access (read and modify) different memory locations concurrently, with no interference and no synchronization requirements.

struct S {
    char a;     // memory location #1
    int b : 5;  // memory location #2
    int c : 11, // memory location #2 (continued)
          : 0,
        d : 8;  // memory location #3
    struct {
        int ee : 8; // memory location #4
    } e;
} obj; // The object 'obj' consists of 4 separate memory locations
```

that means we can use two threads to change S s::a and S s::b without thinking the sync of S s?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that bit fields do not start new memory locations even if they straddle multiple bytes and some parts are aligned to other bytes. Note that while it is allowed to consider different members to be different entities (at least, when they are not bit fields) it will be a bad idea as false sharing will just slow your program down.

Comment: What is S s?  I don't see any 's' in the given struct.

Comment: @Dietmar That looks like an answer, and yes bit fields behave like what you said unless explicitly separated by `: 0`

Comment: "As a special case, an unnamed bit-field with a width of zero
specifies alignment of the next bit-field at an allocation unit boundary". Not sure if "allocation unit boundary" means "memory location" though.

Comment: @PasserBy: I don't see the any special handling of `:0` fields in a bit-field in the text talking about data races and bit-fields. More specifically I don't think the text on data races talks about memory locations anyway but about objects or bit-fields. While the example is taken from the section on the memory model, it doesn't seem data races special case it.

Answer (score 0):

From n4296 in 2014 at least, section 1.7.3:

> A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having
>   non-zero width.

So yes, your intuition seems correct that you can read and write to them from separate threads without synchronizing.

Also, this seems at least tangentially relevant from section 9.6.2 in that same draft:

> As a special case, an unnamed bit-field with a width of zero
>   specifies alignment of the next bit-field at an allocation unit boundary

The same verbiage is in n4659 from 2017 in sections 4.4.3 and 12.2.4.2, respectively.

I don't see the exact verbiage as the OP in n4296, but this is in section 1.7.3:

> Two or more threads of execution (1.10) can update and access separate memory
>   locations without interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you?

To a certain extent, yes. However, if you need `s` to deference and access the different members/locations, then no. (And it should be obvious you cannot have another thread destroy `s` concurrently.)

> Should you?

In this case almost certainly not. Otherwise you're simply breaking down an encapsulation that was supposed to simplify design by fiddling in nitty-gritty details.

That said, the principle is important with a more practical example:
When you have a collection of objects, different threads can operate on different elements without concurrency concerns: *provided adding/removing/moving items in the collection has appropriate thread safety in place*.

### CAUTION

You may need to pay attention to machine architecture to be certain of thread safety of unaligned, adjacent memory locations. (Even if the hardware protects you, this could come at a performance cost.)